# How can I make sense of this C type declaration?

Tags: c, declaration

```
double (*bar(int, double(*)(double,double[])))(double);
```

While reviewing a lecture slide, I found an exercise left to the student:

> In plain English, what is the type of `bar` in this C declaration?

*Please* help walk me through this. I don't even know where to begin, except that something is ultimately returning a double.

Comment: don't know what the type is, but suddenly I'm thinking Tim Hortons for some reason...

Comment: declare bar as function (int, pointer to function (double, array of double) returning double) returning pointer to function (double) returning double.  (I [cheated](http://cdecl.org/).)

Comment: (And that's a lot of double-talk.)

Comment: The first reaction should be to catch the poor bastard who codes like that, and yell at him in plain English :)

Comment: This question is why typedef should be used liberally

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand why this question was closed as "too localized". While the exact line of code won't come up and need to be understood by most people, the ability to understand complex C declarations is a very useful skill... this question just exemplifies it.

Comment: @Mike you may be right, but with the current title you won't get that. Someone should edit it to make less localized and more search friendly

Comment: Bam, done...100% pure magic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is brought to you by the ability to use the [Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Being able to understand a complex expression by starting at the unknown element and reading around it (resolving things in the parenthesis first). A very useful skill when reading code.

```
        bar                                            - bar
        bar()                                          - is a function
        bar(int, )                                     - which takes an int...
        bar(int, (*)())                                - and a function pointer
        bar(int, double(*)())                          - which returns a double
        bar(int, double(*)(double, ))                  - and takes a double...
        bar(int, double(*)(double, double[]))          - and an array of doubles
      (*bar(int, double(*)(double, double[])))         - and returns a pointer
      (*bar(int, double(*)(double, double[])))()       - to a function
      (*bar(int, double(*)(double, double[])))(double) - taking a double
double(*bar(int, double(*)(double, double[])))(double) - which returns a double
```

That was the hard way... There are of course sites that make this easier, the [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) site for example; but it's good to be able to read code even when you can't get to the internet.

Answer (score 10):

If you're not sure you can always use the cdecl utility described in K&R like so:

```
$ cdecl
Type `help' or `?' for help
cdecl> explain double (*bar(int, double(*)(double,double[])))(double);
declare bar as function 
(int, pointer to function (double, array of double) returning double)
returning pointer to function (double) returning double
```

So bar is a function that takes an `int` and a pointer to a function that takes a `double` and `double[]` and returns a `double`:

```
double(*)(double,double[]))
```

And bar returns a pointer to another function that takes a `double` and returns a `double`

```
double(*)(double)
```

Comment: @Aerovistae If by "that" you mean the declaration from the slide, I guess it's there to subject students to a cruel and unusual punishment ;-)

Comment: Is it just me, or is the original code easier to read compared to that particular output of cdecl? :-P

Comment: @NikosC. No, the output of `cdecl` isn't easier to read/understand, since it is just another type of plaintext code and not human brain-native AST.

Comment: @NikosC. There's small choice in rotten apples :)

Comment: @NikosC. this explains OP's comment "Why does that exist?" :)

Comment: Some OCD part of me hates picking the less-voted answer, and this is a great answer, but that guy really spelled it out.

Comment: @Aerovistae Pick the answer that helped **you** most. That's what the checkmark is meant to indicate. Only if you pick a downvoted answer (and perhaps not even then if it's at -1) have you reason to stop and think whether you should really accept that one.

Comment: @Aerovistae it's okay no need to explain :) I upvoted the other answer myself, I wasn't going for full explanation anyway I wanted you to figure it out yourself.