# What does the C declaration signify?

Tags: c

Consider the below C declaration:

```
typedef char (* ( * (* ARR ) ( ) ) [8]) (int,int) ;    
ARR arr;
```

What does `arr` signify?

Comment: Why make a language unreadable like that? God..

Comment: Use [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=char+%28*+%28+*+%28*+ARR+%29+%28+%29+%29+[8]%29+%28int%2Cint%29).

Comment: see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13592447/1157444)

Comment: It indicates that someone is likely to have an aneurysm whilst reading your code.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra sometimes instructors give assignments like that, normally no one would write that.

Comment: @mux Ya.. I know.. Too bad people judges others based on how much they make simple things difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do parentheses in a C variable declaration mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244680/what-do-parentheses-in-a-c-variable-declaration-mean)

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: I've used structures like this in production code before (although not with this much indirection); building function lookup tables isn't that uncommon.

Comment: Why do people downvote without telling why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the leftmost identifier, then work your way out remembering that `[]` and `()` bind before `*`, so `*a[]` is an array of pointer, `(*a)[]` is a pointer to an array, `*f()` is a function returning a pointer, and `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function:

```
typedef                ARR                           -- ARR is a typedef for
                    (* ARR )                         -- a pointer
                    (* ARR ) ( )                     -- to a function
                ( * (* ARR ) ( ) )                   -- returning a pointer
                ( * (* ARR ) ( ) ) [8]               -- to an 8-element array
             (* ( * (* ARR ) ( ) ) [8])              -- of pointers
             (* ( * (* ARR ) ( ) ) [8]) (       )    -- to functions
             (* ( * (* ARR ) ( ) ) [8]) (int,int)    --   taking two int parameters
typedef char (* ( * (* ARR ) ( ) ) [8]) (int,int) ;  --   and returning char
```

So

```
ARR arr;
```

declares `arr` to be a pointer to a function returning a pointer to an 8-element array of pointers to functions returning char.

Here's an example of what this would look like in practice:

```
char f0(int a, int b) { ... }
char f1(int x, int y) { ... }
char f2(int g, int h) { ... }
...
char f7(int r, int s) { ... }

// funcArr is an *array* of pointers to functions, not a function
char (*funcArr[8])(int, int) = {f0, f1, f2, f3, ..., f7}; 

// func is a function that will return the funcArr array
char (*(*func())[8])(int,int) { return funcArr; }

arr = func;

char c = (*(*(*arr)())[i])(x,y);
```

So, the last line

1. dereferences `arr`
2. calls the resulting function (`func`)
3. dereferences the pointer returned from `func`, which gives us the array (`funcArr`)
4. finds the function pointer at index `i`
5. dereferences *that* pointer to give us one of `f0`...`f7`
6. and calls the resulting function

One way of making the `typedef` a little more readable is to do it in stages:

```
typedef char CharFunc(int, int);
typedef CharFunc *CharFuncArray[8];
typedef CharFuncArray *ArrayFunc();

ArrayFunc *arr;
```

Personally, I'm not fond of doing things this way, because it's not obvious how you get from `ArrayFunc *arr` to

```
char c = (*(*(*arr)())[i])(x,y);
```

whereas a declaration like

```
char (*(*(*arr)())[8])(int,int);
```

tells you *exactly* how `arr` is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 3):

`arr` is a `pointer to a function returning pointer to an array of 8 pointers to a function which takes 2 int as an argument returning char`

For more see [this naming of complex declarations using clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Answer (score 2):

`arr` is a pointer to a function returning pointer to a array 8 pointers to a function which takes 2 parameters as int which is returning character. You definitely need to check this [link](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) which will help you decode such complex declarations.

PS: I suggest do not have such complex declarations. Break it up into parts.

Comment: And I suggest you don't use pointers to functions returning pointers to arrays of pointers to other functions. If you do, your next question here will likely be "Why doesn't this work?". :-)